# Bar chart shrink behaviour when scrolling horizontally with setInScroll enabled

Tags: android, charts, achartengine, horizontalscrollview

I'm creating a dynamic bar charts using achartengine in my application. Bar charts are used to display weekly work data in hours and they are scrollable horizontally (each bar chart have its own view with width of screen). I've placed bar charts in HorizontallScrollView with infinity scroll and sticking enabled (by swapping views with each other) and when I'm scrolling to either left or right the bar charts shrinks to the side of screen instead of being scrolled out of screen like rest of views. I've found that I should enable setInScroll on renderer of my chart to get rid of this behaviour but sadly this doesn't work (chart shrinks with setInScroll set to true). I'm out of ideas how to fix that. Here's my renderer setup:

```
private static XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getRenderer(List<Integer> list, int[] weekdays)
{
    float maxValue = 0;
    for (Integer value : list){
        if (value > maxValue){
            maxValue = value;
        }
    }
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#' h'");
    formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
    maxValue = maxValue/60;
    maxValue = maxValue + (float)(maxValue*0.2);
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    XYSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    seriesRenderer.setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.ActionBarBlue));
    seriesRenderer.setChartValuesFormat(formatter);
    seriesRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    seriesRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    seriesRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(12);
    seriesRenderer.setChartValuesTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);

    for (int i=0; i < 7; i++){
        renderer.addXTextLabel(i+1, mDays[i] + " " + weekdays[i]);
    }

    renderer.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor((R.color.White)));
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(false);
    renderer.setInScroll(true);
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0});
    renderer.setAntialiasing(true);
    renderer.setMarginsColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.White));
    renderer.setShowLegend(false);
    renderer.setXAxisMin(0.5);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(7.5);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(maxValue);
    renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setGridColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.Gray));
    renderer.setXLabelsColor(mContext.getResources().getColor((R.color.Black)));
    renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, mContext.getResources().getColor((R.color.White)));
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(12);
    renderer.setXLabels(0);
    renderer.setYLabels(0);
    return renderer;
}
```

Comment: Please post a screenshot such as we can understand how the chart is shrinking.

Comment: I already got that fixed by simply... rebooting my PC. There was some problem with Android Studio and java in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears it was some kind of problem with Android Studio and java, not responding to any changes in code i made, rebooting PC worked.